# Difference between factory reset and forgotten password erase all data

Tags: recovery-mode, lock-screens, factory-reset

Is there a difference between performing a reset from recovery mode, or clicking on the forgotten password button on the locked screen, which offers to "erase all data"? I assume there isn't, but I wanted to be sure.
I don't know if this is useful information or not but I have a Redmi Note 8.

Thanks!

Update: Clicking on the "Next" button on the forgot password screen that informs me it will delete all data just shows instructions on how to get into recovery mode, so it turns out there aren't actually two ways to reset this device in case of forgotten password like it seemed.

Comment: Usually they both are the same. But it depends on the OEM. They can implement them differently.

Comment: Beware it will activate FRP and requires both, google play account + mi account to unlock!

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip! I was not logged in with a mi account so I assume that won't be a problem. As for google, would I be able to use it to unlock my phone instead? I read that it should appear as an option after several unsuccessful attempts but it never did for me, despite being signed in.

Comment: google stopped offering all screenlock by-pass options via google account, what you have read is therefore outdated

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!